# MySQL table is marked as crashed, how to get the crashed table by query

Tags: mysql, c-api

I want to get crashed table list from query by **C API**.

I know about `mysqlcheck --auto-repair --check --all-database` command and `repair table db_name.table_name` in the cli, but I can't find out how to get the crashed table name by query.

I just want to get the table name by query, such as

```
select table_name from some_specific_db where status=crashed
```

Does anyone have know this?

Comment: SHOW TABLE STATUS;

Comment: what column says the table is crashed?

Comment: AFAIK when ENGINE is null

Comment: unfortunately, I can't find any kind of different things in column of crashed table of 'show table status' command.

Answer (score 0):

```
show table status where comment like '%crash%';
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Thanks for taking the time to write an answer to this question. It is always a good idea to write a few words of explanation in addition to any code you put in your answer. You can easily [edit] your answer to add this explanation, I suggest you do so. This will help OP and anybody else with the same question to understand your answer.